# String Format: How to add any number of zeros before string

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to have strings that have zeros before them.

I use this code:

```
string a = string.Format("{0:00}",7);
```

The above code gives a two digits string, but what if I want a `n` digit string? Let's say `n = 5`, how can I use `string.format` to get something like `0004`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int num = 4;    
string a = num.ToString("D4");
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString)

Comment: If it is 5, you may use `strings = 4.ToString("D5");`

Comment: Thanks Moayad, I'm using something like this: `string a = number.ToString("D"+length);`

Answer (score 1):

This will print with leading 4 zeros.

```
int maxwidth = 5;
Console.WriteLine(outstring.PadLeft(maxwidth, '0'));
```

Working [fiddler sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b2Zlq0)

Comment: Not a correct solution. If the input is 115, the output will be 0000115. The expected output is 0115.

Comment: @Akbari it works the same way you explained. Check this [fiddler link] (https://dotnetfiddle.net/E6DFG9)

Comment: Yes, it works fine now. Thanks for your time and effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this

```
string formatstring = "{0:0000}"; // or anything else I want it to be
int i = 4; // any number I want
strings = string.Format(formatstring, i);
```

to change the formatting based on the the number of digits

```
formatstring = "{0:";
for(int x=0; x< i.ToString().Length; x++)
    formatstring += "0";
formatstring += "}";
```

Comment: The format string is hardcoded in this example but can be dynamically changed at runtime in your program.

Comment: Yes, but how should I change the number of zeros in this way? Let's say, we might need 7 zeros based on the variable `n`.

Comment: `string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("0", n))` something like this.

Comment: added code for number of digits, @n0rd has a good idea as well. It is up to you how you would want to do it.

Comment: Do not concatenate string repeatedly. It is slow. It does tons of completely unnecessary memory allocations. Use `StringBuilder` with preallocated buffer instead (even without preallocated buffer it is better than concatenating strings).